# RNG not behaving as I expected

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry for the very vague title, I'm not really sure how to describe my problem.

I'm making a game that involves lots of tiny cells that will randomly move around on the screen, but the problem is they all seem to gravitate toward the top-left of the screen. It's not just me getting unlucky, they always go to the top-left.

Here is the code in question:

```
    for cell in cell_list:

            direction = randint(0, 3)

            if direction == 0:
                    cell.rect.x += cell.speed
            elif direction == 1:
                        cell.rect.x -= cell.speed
            elif direction == 2:
                    cell.rect.y += cell.speed
            elif direction == 3:
                    cell.rect.y -= cell.speed
```

Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/3hK4s2qL (use Python 3.4)

Comment: you need to cut down on the code so that only the part that's not working is included. Gut the color stuff if its unrelated.

Comment: `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` this implies that this may not be the most updated version. please check

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I swear I only put the non-working portion... let me fix this. Also, I'm using Python 3, and you don't need to pass super arguments in that

Comment: Is there bound to your rectangle where you draw points and also what happens when the point co-ordinates are out of bound ?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the random number generator. `cell.rect.x` and `cell.rect.y` are integers, while `cell.speed` is not. When you add `cell.speed` to `cell.rect.x` or `cell.rect.y`, the result is rounded -- probably with a floor function, hence the bias towards the upper left. Notice that if you hard-code the cell speed as 1 (or any integer), the problem disappears. If you want to keep the small variation in cell speed, you could create `cell.x` and `cell.y` and then do this:

```
for cell in cell_list:
    direction = randint(0, 3)

    if direction == 0:
        cell.x += cell.speed
    elif direction == 1:
        cell.x -= cell.speed
    elif direction == 2:
        cell.y += cell.speed
    elif direction == 3:
        cell.y -= cell.speed
    cell.rect.x = cell.x
    cell.rect.y = cell.y
```

That way, even though the display gets rounded to an integer, `cell.x` and `cell.y` keep track of the "real" location and there won't be a bias. If you don't need to have small variation in speed, just use randint to generate it.

Comment: Right solution. You could maybe go a step further and make `x` and `y` properties that automatically update `cell.rect.x` and `cell.rect.y`.